# Jquery $.ajax - Error: SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use .start().done() or .start().fail()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my javascript codes :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Users_Area/Order.aspx/Get_Server_Date",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",
    async: true,
    success: function(result) {
        server_date = new Date(result.d);
        //alert(server_date);

        var Order_id = $("#<%= hf_order_id.ClientID %>").val();
        alert(Order_id);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Users_Area/Order.aspx/Get_Order_Date",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'Order_id': '" + Order_id + "'}",
            async: true,
            success: function(result) {
                order_date = new Date(result.d);
                alert(order_date);

                if (server_date > order_date) {
                    var dif_server_order_in_seconds = (server_date - order_date) / 1000;
                    alert(dif_server_order_in_seconds);
                    if (dif_server_order_in_seconds > 3600) {

                    } else {}
                }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

And here is console error after `alert(order_date);` line :

> Browser Link: Failed to send message to browser link server: Error:
> SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized. Use
> .start().done() or .start().fail() to run logic after the connection
> has started.

How can i fix this problem?

> (I am using asp.net webforms with c#)

Comment: [This is about .done() and .fail() > Both of them has depricated](https://riptutorial.com/jquery/example/30084/jquery-ajax---success--error--vs---done-----fail--)

Comment: After refresh page error vanish - What is wrong about my codes?